# Find a function $F(x)$ whose derivative is $f(x) = \sin(3x)$, without using integrals

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find a function $F(x)$  whose derivative is $f(x) = \sin(3x)$.

I'm not supposed to use integrals.

How to do this?

Comment: I can't understand, and even less seeing the answers, how doing this exercise is *not* equivalent to do an (indefinite) integral...Perhaps the lecturer just don't want to see the integral sign? In fact, the very name "indefinite integral" is pretty sloppy and poor, as the actual operation should perhaps more properly be called antiderivation...but this discussion doens't belong here.

Comment: Indefinite integration is a perfectly well defined operation on $ L^1\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{R}$ . Try telling that to your freshman calc class.

Answer (score 2):

You know that the derivative of $\cos(x)$ is $-\sin(x)$, and you know the chain rule. So it's immediate that you're looking for $-\frac{1}{3} \cos(3x)$.

Comment: Your solution is undoubtedly what is asked for. But I think of the procedure you described as a (quite useful) method of integration.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Indeed!

Answer (score 2):

In problems like this, try to construct a function that you know has a derivative that is equal to $\sin(3x)$. For example, we know that $$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(3x)) = -3 \sin(3x)$$ by the chain rule.

Now, we don't want the factor $-3$...we want the function whose derivative is simply $\sin(3x)$.

So let's try multiplying $\cos(3x)$ by $-\large\frac 13:\,$ that gives us $F(x) = -\dfrac 13 \cos(3x)$.

Now check whether $$F'(x) = \dfrac {d}{dx}\left(-\frac 13 \cos(3x)\right)\quad \overset{?} = \quad\sin(3x)$$

If the equality holds, (and you'll see it does hold) you've got your needed function: $$F(x)= \left(-\frac 13 \cos(3x)\right)$$

Sometimes, with more complicated functions, this process proceeds with a little trial-and-error.